# Why using string indexer on 'Settings.Default' to change a property value is not saved/persisted?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, save, application-settings

I have a .NET Framework app, and I need to save and load the state of bool variable. I tried to do this, using MyApp.Properties library. Here my code for save:

```
        private static void ChangeBoolState()
        {
            warningMessageState = false;
            Settings.Default["warningMessageState"] = warningMessageState;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

And here for load:

```
 warningMessageState = Convert.ToBoolean(Settings.Default["warningMessageState"]);
```

When I try to load or to save this variable using this code, I get the error:

```
System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException: "Settings property 'warningMessageState' could not be found."
```

Anybody know, what am I doing wrong? Thank You in advance!

Comment: How did you create `warningMessageState` ? Using the Solution Explorer to open the settings file and the Visual Studio Designer to edit the list as an array ? In all cases you should use: `Properties.Settings.Default.warningMessageState` if you can avoid using indexer like here unless there is a good reason like accessing settings from an external library or a very different namespace, but in this case you need to pass the current application settings instance to this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- On the project menu click properties
- On the left click settings
- Something like this appears (or maybe "this project doesn't contain a Settings file, click here to create one" - click there):
  [image]
- Make sure that grid contains a **User Scoped bool** named WarningMessageState (use pascal case; it will end up as a class property)
- Then you can use code like:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.WarningMessageState = true;

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

if(Properties.Settings.Default.WarningMessageState)
    MessageBox.Show("Warning!");
```

Comment: Hello Caius Jard! Thank You for Your answer! This is resolve my problem!```:)```